# Phonegap-contact plugin. How to pick a contact number and show it in the input field?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I have a hybrid application based on `phone-gap` where I have to pick one contact from the native contact API and show the number in the input field.

I am using the following function:

```
pickContact: function() {
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact) {
        alert('The following contact has been selected:' + JSON.stringify(contact));
    }, function(err) {
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    });
}
```

Problems:

1. How to show the phone number in the input field?
2. When one contact has multiple numbers, how to show all the numbers while selecting and select only one particular number on click?

Comment: also you can bind variable directly inside pickContact like `$scope.number = contact` and bind `number` in view

Comment: i am not sure what ngCorova return when we select contact with multiple number

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge. I am already done with the component .Phone-gap will return the first number saved for the particular contact .I have tried and tested the same.